# Limit of smallest real solution to equation

Tags: convergence-divergence

I think if you solve $$x \sum_{i=0}^{n} (1-x)^i = 0.085$$ for x, the equation always has one real solution such that $0 \leq x \leq 1$, and as $n \rightarrow \infty$, this solution converges towards 0.085 (EDIT: sorry, this was wrong in the original question ... I mean converges to $\frac{0.085}{n}$). (Presumably 0.085 could be replaced by any number between 0 and 1 ...)

Could anyone point me into some direction if I wanted to prove that there is always one such solution (real between 0 and 1) and that it converges towards $\frac{0.085}{n}$? I have basically no education in the subject.

(This is also not a homework question ... it came up as part of my work)

Comment: Sorry ... I realized 30 seconds after submitting I had forgotten a fraction in the question ... I edited for clarification but now I'm not sure anymore the question makes sense :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the sum
$$\sum_{i=0}^n (1-x)^i = \frac{1-(1-x)^{n+1}}{x}$$

So your equation is equivalent to
$$1-(1-x)^{n+1} = 0.085$$
i.e.
$$(1-x)^{n+1} = 0.915$$

i.e., if $0 \leq x \leq 1$, 
$$1-x = \sqrt[n+1]{0.915}$$

i.e. 
$$x = 1-\sqrt[n+1]{0.915}$$

This tends to $1$ as $n \rightarrow + \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If we write $t=1-x$ then we have $$(1-t)\sum_{i=0}^{n}t^i = 0.085$$

so $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}t^i-\sum_{i=0}^{n}t^{i+1} = 0.085$$

so $${t^{n+1}-1\over t-1}-{t^{n+2}-1\over t-1} = 0.085$$

so $$ t^{n+1}-t^{n+2} = 0.085(t-1)$$

so $$1-t^{n+1} =0.085$$  so $$1-x = \sqrt[n]{0.915}\implies x = 1-\sqrt[n]{0.915}\to 1$$

Comment: I believe this down vote was based on personal level.